# marginBottom and marginTop with percentage cutting children

Tags: react-native

- [x] I have reviewed the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native)
- [x] I have searched [existing issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues)
- [x] I am using the [latest React Native version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases)
- [x] Open [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19164)

[iOS] When you use percentage in marginBottom or marginTop it kind cuts the children inside. 
Tested with Text, and Views component

Devices:  [Simulator iPhone 5s, Simulator iPhone 7, Simulator iPhone X, Real device iPhone 6s]

[Android] Sometimes happens to the views only.
Devices: Samsung S5 mini

For some reason with marginHorizontal:"20%"  or if we remove the "flex:1" from the main View the bug doesn't occur. 
But sometimes even without "flex:1" property the bug still occurs. There should be a group of properties that activate this bug or not.

On React-Native V0.53.3 this bug doesn't happen.

### Environment

Environment:

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Node: 9.8.0

Yarn: 1.6.0

npm: 6.0.0

Watchman: 4.9.0

Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145

Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4720617

Packages:
  react: 16.3.1

react-native: 0.55.3

### Steps to Reproduce

https://snack.expo.io/rJtl8WR6G

```
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
    <View style={{ marginTop: "8%"}}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '700' }}>ASdsad</Text> 
    </View>
  </View>
```

### Expected Behavior

To not cut the children!

### Actual Behavior

Cutting the Children!